# Testing Angular $resource with external service

Tags: rest, testing, angularjs

I'm trying to make some basic tests on REST requests I'm doing using Angular $resource.
The service code works just fine.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('lelylan.services', ['ngResource']).
  factory('Device', ['Settings', '$resource', '$http', function(Settings, $resource, $http) {

    var token = 'df39d56eaa83cf94ef546cebdfb31241327e62f8712ddc4fad0297e8de746f62';
    $http.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = 'Bearer ' + token;

    var resource = $resource(
      'http://localhost:port/devices/:id',
      { port: ':3001', id: '@id' },
      { update: { method: 'PUT' } }
    );

    return resource;
  }]);
```

I'm using the Device resource inside a directive and it works. The problems comes out 
when I start making some tests on the services. Here is a sample test where I mock the 
HTTP request using $httpBackend and I make a request to the mocked URL.

Unluckily it does not return anything, although the request is made. I'm sure about this
because if a request to another URL is made, the test suite automatically raises an error.
I've been spending lot of time, but no solutions. Here the test code.

```
'use strict';

var $httpBackend;

describe('Services', function() {

  beforeEach(module('lelylan'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
    var uri = 'http://localhost:3001/devices/50c61ff1d033a9b610000001';
    var device = { name: 'Light', updated_at: '2012-12-20T18:40:19Z' };
    $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
    $httpBackend.whenGET(uri).respond(device)
  }));

  describe('Device#get', function() {
    it('returns a JSON', inject(function(Device) {
      device = Device.get({ id: '50c61ff1d033a9b610000001' });
      expect(device.name).toEqual('Light');
    }));
  });
});
```

As the device is not loaded this is the error.

```
Expected undefined to equal 'Light'.
Error: Expected undefined to equal 'Light'.
```

I've tried also using the following solution, but it doesn't get into the function
to check the expectation.

```
it('returns a JSON', inject(function(Device) {
  device = Device.get({ id: '50c61ff1d033a9b610000001' }, function() {
    expect(device.name).toEqual('Light');
  });
}));
```

Any suggestion or link to solve this problem is really appreciated.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were very close, the only thing missing was a call to the `$httpBackend.flush();`. The working test looks like follows:

```
it('returns a JSON', inject(function(Device) {
  var device = Device.get({ id: '50c61ff1d033a9b610000001' });
  $httpBackend.flush();
  expect(device.name).toEqual('Light');
}));
```

and a live test in plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Pp0LbLHs0Qxlgqkl948l?p=preview

You might also want to check [docs for the $httpBackend mock](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.$httpBackend).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was making some tests with it. I was totally missing the #flush part. Also thanks a lot for the really nice live example. Love it.

Answer (score 0):

In later versions of angular, I'm using 1.2.0rc1 you also need to call this within a $apply or call $digest on a scope.  The resource call isn't made unless you do something like this:

```
var o, back, scope;

beforeEach(inject(function( $httpBackend, TestAPI,$rootScope) {
    o = TestAPI;
    back = $httpBackend;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

}));

it('should call the test api service', function() {
    back.whenGET('/api/test').respond({});
    back.expectGET('/api/test');
    scope.$apply( o.test());
    back.flush();
});
```