# ngMock is throwing template load error because of ngRoute's $routeProvider...?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, ngroute, angular-amd

I just included ngMock into my project because I need it for $httpBackend. I have a bunch of karma/jasmine tests setup, and after including ngMock, everything is breaking because of an error it causes:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Windows 7): Executed 0 of 41 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Windows 7) ERROR
  Error: Unexpected request: GET home/home.html
  No more request expected
  at C:/dev/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1181
```

Seems that it doesn't like ngRoute/$routeProvider. Specifically it breaks on the otherwise/redirectTo statement. If I comment-out that section, the karma/jasmine tests work without error.

```
  $routeProvider
    .when('/home', angularAMD.route({
      templateUrl: 'home/home.html',
      controller: ''
    }))
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/home'
    });
```

Notice, I am using angularAMD (for lazy loading), but even when I rewrite that section to use just {} without the angularAMD.route(), it still throws the same error. ie:

```
  $routeProvider
    .when('/home', {
      templateUrl: 'home/home.html',
      controller: ''
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/home'
    });
```

Any idea why ngMock doesn't like ngRoute? For now I've created a workaround where I skip the $routeProvider section while running karma/jasmine tests. But I'm trying to understand what is going on, am I not supposed to be setting $routeProvider during unit-testing at all (is that bad practice)?

**[Edit:]** Issues seem to appear in other segments as well. I'm running a test that includes a service which is loading a template, and it also throws an error:

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET components/modal/modal.html
No more request expected
    at $httpBackend (C:/dev/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1181)
```

**[Edit:]** Seems to throw the error when I call `$httpBackend.flush();`

**[Edit:]** Great, found posts related to issue. Can't believe Google didn't show any relevant results when I searched. **Solution:** If you found yourself here from Google Results, take a look at these: [post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16795617/4038821), [post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18368287/4038821).

**[Edit:]** Couldn't get any of those solutions working with angularAMD. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? Having the exact same problem!

Comment: @stianlip yeah, you need to setup a catch-all to funnel all unresolved templates: `$httpBackend.whenGET(/\.html$/g).respond("");` And in my tests, I use a separate `app.js` file to bootstrap the app, which doesn't declare any $routeProvider config.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I wasn't loading the complete module for the app (which is what I was associating ngRoute with).

In my `User.tests.js` file, I had

```
 beforeEach(module('App.services'));
```

In my `app.js` file I had:

```
  App = angular.module("App", [
    "ngRoute"
    "App.templates"
    "App.filters"
    "App.services"
    "App.controllers"
    "App.directives"
    "ui.bootstrap"
  ]);
```

In my `User.js` service, I was actually utilizing the `$route`. **The solution** *for me* was to switch my `User.tests.js` to use the mock module `"App"` - `beforeEach(module("App"))`; this way the tests are loading all the correct dependencies.